# how can I represent road shape in weighed graph for route planning

Tags: tree, maps, openstreetmap, graph-theory

I've decided to build a route-planner for a game similar to Google Maps to expand my knowledge of graphs and to serve as portfolio project.

I've done my research and got to the conclusion that I need to represent the roads as nodes in a weighted graph but my understanding is that only intersections are represented.

My question is how would I also represent the shape of the road?

My reasoning on how to solve this product would be that the graph node would have the link-cost and then as data would hold an object (JSON) with the information pertaining to the road shape until the next node/intersection.

That poses some problems because what if I want to plan a route to the middle of a road. Take the figure below, I want to go from C to what is essentially between D and E but on the road above.

Figure:
Note that all of the roads are two ways so you can assume that the edges are directed and weighed.

[image: Figure 1]

I've tried to look into how OSM does this but the data size alone throws me off.

Any resources would be very appreciated :)

Comment: I have found a StackOverflow answering this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177343/map-navigation-project-how-is-road-data-generally-stored-represented?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation , if you want a JSON based format, is to look into GeoJSON. This is a well established format that can represent both spatial/shape features, and non spatial features such as street names, addresses, etc. There is extensive documentation online , so I won't quote specific links. Also the GIS Stack Exchange is a good resource for this type of problem.